# Material ToolTip which gets its text from parent (anchor)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I want to use ToolTip like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
     [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
     return <div (onClick)={() => {setOpen(!open)}> Click to open tooltip
              <Tooltip text="some text from parent open={open} >
 </div>
}
```

Is there any way to do this way?

Comment: Was my answer able to solve your problem? If not, please provide more information and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You would pass the text in as props from the parent

```
function MyComopnent(props) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    return <div onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}><Tooltip text={props.text} /></div>;
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <MyComponent text="Some text from the parent" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Check out more information [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).